# Don't update watch output unless the command succeeds

Tags: linux, unix, watch

Is there a way to get `watch` to update the screen when the command succeeds? I have a command that infrequently succeeds, and I want it to show the last successful output.

Is there a way without a helper program?

Answer (score 0):

`watch` does not allow to conditionally show the output of a command, but you can start your command from script and show its output depending on the termination status. Use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd > /tmp/cmd_out
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    cat /tmp/cmd_out
fi
```

Of course, your command should return proper exit status (not just 0 in any case) or this method will not work.